# EKS ingress controller creation not seeing tagged subnets?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm new to EKS, and am following the examples to set up a sample app that creates an ingress controller, ingress, service, and deployment from [How do I set up the ALB Ingress Controller on an Amazon EKS cluster for Fargate?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-alb-ingress-controller-fargate/). I have everything created (deployements, pods, service, iam, service account, etc.) but my ingress controller is failing to come up with the error

```
E0224 19:09:07.053006       1 controller.go:217] kubebuilder/controller "msg"="Reconciler error" "error"="failed to build LoadBalancer configuration due to retrieval of subnets failed to resolve 2 qualified subnets. Subnets must contain the kubernetes.io/cluster/\u003ccluster name\u003e tag with a value of shared or owned and the kubernetes.io/role/elb tag signifying it should be used for ALBs Additionally, there must be at least 2 subnets with unique availability zones as required by ALBs. Either tag subnets to meet this requirement or use the subnets annotation on the ingress resource to explicitly call out what subnets to use for ALB creation. The subnets that did resolve were []"  "controller"="alb-ingress-controller" "request"={"Namespace":"mynamespace","Name":"2048-ingress"}
```

I do have my VPCs and subnets tagged appropriately per [Application load balancing on Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html) and other pages that shows how to tag my VPCs and subnets.

One question I have, my ingress manifest has

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "2048-ingress"
  namespace: "mynamespace"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I had to add the tags to the public subnets of my VPC, even though this is a private only cluster.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but did you notice any logs which tries to delete the security group listed in alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-1234567890? I am having this issue as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66552105/why-delete-is-attempted-on-the-security-group-provided-in-alb-ingress-kubernetes and looking for some help

Comment: @Vishal i didn't have to add the security group to either my ingress controller or ingress resources.