# Why delete is attempted on the security group provided in alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups annotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an EKS cluster and I am using aws-load-balancer-controller:v2.1.1. I am using the below aws alb ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-alb-ingress
  namespace: myns
  labels: 
    app: myns-alb-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Team=myteam
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: my-apps
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:xxx
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}, {"HTTP":80}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
```

Also there is a security group "sg-xxxxc91467c97bbb" with the description "[k8s] Managed SecurityGroup for LoadBalancer".

I have a bunch of IP addresses added in this Security Group as inbound rules. Now whenever I add any host rules (path/ backend service ) and apply this ingress, all the inbound rules of this security group gets deleted and 0.0.0.0/0 gets added automatically.

**How can I prevent this from happening so that I retain my inbound rules?**

I tried adding

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-xxxxc91467c97bbb
```

to the annotations above and it retains all the rules. However in the output of

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system   deployment.apps/aws-load-balancer-controller
```

I see logs like

```
{"level":"info","ts":1615287229.3065767,"logger":"controllers.ingress","msg":"deleting securityGroup","securityGroupID":"sg-xxxxc91467c97bbb"}
```

and in the ingress describe, I see event like

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------             ----                   ----     -------
  Warning  FailedDeployModel  5m2s (x9 over 20m)  ingress  Failed deploy model due to failed to delete securityGroup: timed out waiting for the condition
```

So if I provide the security group in the annotations, the inbound rules are retained but something tries to delete the security group itself which I don't want. Any suggestions?

Comment: For anyone facing similar issue, this is the response for the ticket I raised with the aws team  https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/1876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced similar issues so I created a new security group (sg-xxxxxxx042) with all necessary inbound rules and passed it to annotation as follows.

alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-xxxxxxx042

along with that, I needed to add one more inbound rule to security groups attached to the eks worker nodes (ec2 instances)

In my case security group name starts with eks-remoteAccess-****  which is attached to the instance.

I added the following inbound rule

Alltraffic      All     All  custom sg-xxxxxxx042